# Unexpected token < AND Define is not defined

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Two weeks ago my Ember application was working. I got back into it today and before making any further changes, I ran "Ember Server". I got this two errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
application.js:1Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

I'm at lost on how to fix this. Any hint on how to approach this issue would be appreciated.

I'm using ember-cli 0.2.3. Node is 0.12.2.

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by the adaptor not being able to communicate with Firebase database due to my corporation firewall. Reverting to using port 3000 (which is the port to use to go through my corporation firewall resolved the issue).